# SVG background not being add as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm creating website using CSS, HTML and BOOTSTRAP.. in my below code i tried to do same design (text overlapped with image) as in image below

[image]

but actually when adding any svgs on left and right side it goes in new line and not as i wanted to, i tried also cols but it takes too small size from the design .. is there any way to add background as svg on left for ex or is there any way to do it better?

```css
#FifthBlock {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, #19191a 50%, #ffffff 23%);
}

.steptext {
  left       : 98px !important;
  position   : relative;
  background : white;
  height     : 101px;
  padding    : 44px;
  margin-top : 29px;
  text-align : end;
  width      : 371px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row" id="FifthBlock">
  <div class="container" id="Fifth" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">
      <h5 class="steptext">blablabla
      </h5>
      <img src="https://proest.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Civil-Engineering-Projects.jpg" style="max-width: 200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <h5 class="steptext">blablabla</h5>
      <img src="https://proest.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Civil-Engineering-Projects.jpg" style="max-width: 200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <h5 class="steptext">blablabla
      </h5>
      <img src="https://proest.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Civil-Engineering-Projects.jpg" style="max-width: 200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: there is no SVG in your code.

Comment: Your snippet needs to be a minimal example which replicates the problem. Note that for any images to show up, they will need absolute URLs, not relative ones. That means that you need to reference images which are available on the web, not images which exist only on your local machine.